# Fingerstyle guitar - thumb fretting

Tags: guitar, technique, fingerstyle-guitar

When piece requires fretting 5 independent notes, some chords are really hard to fret. The common situation is when you need to reach octave from bass note on G string and have still three fingers free.

Example: 10x97810

It sometimes causes pain when I try to twist thumb too much. I know everything takes time, but with correct technique it should be accessible. What approaches could help here?

One thing I noticed is that fretting thumb first and pulling string a bit towards edge makes this chord a bit easier. I'm not sure if this should be part of my technique.

Comment: I found this impossible to play anyway. 10 is bottom (fat) string, x is 5th (A) ? It's unusual to use a thumb to fret notes higher than the rest of those in a chord. Or am I missing something ? (Like a strange shaped hand).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of fingerings for that chord that don't require using your L.H. thumb.  The first uses a first finger barre at fret 10; the second uses an open B. It would be easiest if you could get a voicing with the open D as the bass note, but I'm not sure this is possible - if I find one I'll post it…!

[image]

NB: The first shape is "movable", as it doesn't have any open strings, so would be useful whenever you need this particular Major-2nd-inversion voicing (shape), whatever the key.